# Absolute positioning ul leads to strange white-space wrapping issue in Firefox & Opera. How to resolve?

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

I have the following HTML test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Position Break</title>

<style type="text/css">
    section {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%
    }

    li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #list_two {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<section>
<ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
</ul>
</section>

<section>

<ul id="list_two">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
</ul>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The (for me) expected output of which is:

```
Item One Item Two

Item One Item Two
```

i.e. Both lists should be displayed inline. This is the observed output in Chrome (8) and Safari (5.0.3) but both Opera (10.10) and Firefox (3.6) produce an unexpected output:

```
Item One Item Two

Item
One
Item
Two
```

I've tried positioning the containing section element instead of the ul. I've tried assigning explicit width and height values at each step up the DOM but to no avail -- I can't seem to find the combination that will get the Chrome/Safari behaviour in Firefox/Opera. How's it done?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `display: block;` to `section {..}`